# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type-error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, atom-editor

I have the following code (es6 spread Attribute):

```
 return {...state, name: action.payload};
```

The error thrown is: *You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.*

**package.json**

[image]

What else do I need to install in order to make this work. All the other ES6 is working but the spread attribute isn't.

**webpack.config.js**

[image]

Comment: Can you share your webpack configuration? There you will see the loaders that may be needed.

Comment: So package.json isn't enough... I have no loaders whatsoever in my webpack.config.js I' ll ad them now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `ecmascript-6` you need to (1) add `.babelrc` file with the following presets

```
{
  "presets": [ "es2015" ]
}
```

[`es2015`](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#es2015) is the particular one you need.

And then (2) configure your webpack to include

```
module.exports = {
  ...,
  loaders : [
    { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /(node_modules)/, loader: 'babel-loader' }
  ]
}
```

Comment: _"To use ecmascript-6 spread operator you need to ..."_ Sure, but there is no ES6 spread syntax in the OP's example.

Comment: @zeroflagL thanks for the notice. I couldn't find the right way to call `{ ...state}` expression and used `spread operator`. However, I see that my use was technically incorrect. Also, I couldn't find the correct way to call this particular feature. Can you help?

Comment: @zeroflagL I would also like to know the right technical term for it... It says here that this is a spread operator: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html#handling-actions

Comment: I found that it is called 'Object rest spread operator': https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/. In es6-features.org it is called 'Rest parameter': http://es6-features.org/#RestParameter

Comment: @DeividasKaržinauskas Well it is the spread operator for me xd, but I still pefer to wrigth return Object.assign({},state,{user:action.payload}); instead of the above... can get used to some of the ES6 syntax...

Comment: It's not an operator, because there is no result. I.e. you cannot write something like `x =  ...state`. It's a syntax, another way to write something.  `{ ...state}` is equivalent to `{x: state.x, y: state.y etc.}`. This particular feature is the spread properties syntax and it's not part of JavaScript yet. It most likely will be in 2018 / 19. So it's not ES6.

Answer (score 2):

You need have configured babel-loader for js files to transpile

webpack config snippet :

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
      'babel-loader'
    ]
  }
```

Inside module rules.

Also add `.babelrc` file in your projects home directory with below contents

```
{
   "presets" : [
     "latest"
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Installing loaders via npm isn't enough. You have to configure that loaders in your webpack.

Add following in your `webpack.config.js`

```
loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015']
      }
    }
  ]
```

[Using loaders in webpack](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/)

Code above means that, whenever it will find any file that matches `\.js$` pattern (files that ends with .js), babel-loader will be used. (You have already installed babel-loader into your dependencies.

You can also use `loader: 'babel'` instead of `loader: 'babel-loader'. It's the same.